# How to iterate over Multiindex and multiply two columns in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I want iterate over a Multiindex and multiply the 'Supply' column (for the first 10 'Symbols', already ranked) on the first day of the month '2017-01-01' by the 'Price' (of the same 10 Symbols) on each day of the month until the end of month and store values in a new column 'New.Cap', and repeat the same operation for each month.

I have tried a for loop, but couldn't make it work. I was able to get 'Supply' values for the top 10 and multiply it by the price (of the same 'Symbols') on the next day and store it just for '2017-01-02'

My data frame:

```
    Date    Symbol   Market.Cap  Price   Circulating.Supply
    1/1/2017    BTC 16050414526 998.33  16077337
    1/1/2017    ETH 715049311   8.17    87493800
    1/1/2017    XRP 231408729   0.01    36337298649
    1/1/2017    LTC 221718486   4.51    49144154
    1/1/2017    XMR 190983552   13.97   13668252
    1/1/2017    ETC 122202804   1.4      87444118
    1/1/2017   DASH 78524020    11.23    6992839
    1/1/2017    REP 43994860    4        11000000
    1/1/2017    MAID 43862003   0.1     452552412
    1/1/2017    STEEM  36999610 0.16    229582096
    1/1/2017    XEM 30962258    0       8999999999
    1/1/2017    ICN 26381302    0.3      87000000
    1/1/2017    FCT 25392986    2.9     8753219
    1/1/2017   DOGE 24501946    0    1.07544E+11
    1/1/2017   WAVES 22132166   0.22 100000000
    1/1/2017    DGD  18079172   9.04      2000000
    1/2/2017    BTC 16429072864 1021.75 16079300
    1/2/2017    ETH 733331862   8.38    87525306
    1/2/2017    XRP 229312859   0.01    36337298649
    1/2/2017    LTC 228536428   4.65    49158829
    1/2/2017    XMR 219509938   16.05   13675283
    1/2/2017    ETC 125743676   1.44    87476792
    1/2/2017    DASH    82595831    11.81   6994957
    1/2/2017    REP 46101566    4.19    11000000
    1/2/2017    MAID    42320210    0.09    452552412
    1/2/2017    STEEM   35374447    0.15    229645428
    1/2/2017    XEM 30396875    0   8999999999
    1/2/2017    ICN 26451766    0.3 87000000
    1/2/2017    FCT 26119449    2.98    8753219
    1/2/2017    DOGE    24343443    0   1.07557E+11
    1/2/2017    WAVES   23267904    0.23    100000000
    1/2/2017    ZEC 17773124    49.79   356994
    1/3/2017    BTC 16786354619 1043.84 16081362
    1/3/2017    ETH 851511659   9.73    87556829
    1/3/2017    XRP 232046528   0.01    36337298649
    1/3/2017    LTC 227483720   4.63    49172954
    1/3/2017    XMR 220176407   16.09   13681607
    1/3/2017    ETC 130608332   1.49    87508802
    1/3/2017    DASH    89434687    12.78   6997071
    1/3/2017    REP 46955890    4.27    11000000
    1/3/2017    MAID    44863660    0.1 452552412
    1/3/2017    STEEM   36308540    0.16    229753160
    1/3/2017    XEM 32157836    0   8999999999
    1/3/2017    ICN 29520641    0.34    87000000
    1/3/2017    FCT 27402737    3.13    8753219
    1/3/2017    DOGE    24429805    0   1.07571E+11
    1/3/2017    WAVES   23992972    0.24    100000000
```

The index columns are the first two (Date and Symbol).

Here is what I have so far:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')
    df = df.set_index('Symbol', append=True)  
    s = df['Circulating.Supply'].xs('2017-01-01') * df['Price'].xs('2017-01- 02')
    s.index = [np.repeat(pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02'), len(s)), s.index]
    df['New.Cap'] = s
    print(df['New.Cap'].loc['2017-01-02'])
```

Comment: Running `df['Circulating.Supply'].xs('2017-01-01') * df['Price'].xs('2017-01-02')` gives me all NaNs, since the dates are different.

Comment: Please print it for print(df['New.Cap'].loc['2017-01-02']) to see the values.

Comment: `df['New.Cap'] = s` gives ValueError and fails, so I can't

Comment: I'm assuming `Date` is the index col to begin with?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to specify the indexes. 'Date' and 'Symbol' are indexes, this is why you probably got ValueError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
#get top10 rows per datetimes in DatetimeIndex
df = df.groupby(level=0).head(10)

#create MultiIndex
df1 = df.set_index('Symbol', append=True)
#print (df1)

#subtract one day and create MultiIndex
df2 = df.set_index(df.index - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).set_index('Symbol', append=True)
#print (df2)
```

---

```
#multiple both Series from first and second DataFrame
df1['new'] = df1['Circulating.Supply'] * df2['Price']
print (df1)
                    Market.Cap    Price  Circulating.Supply           new
Date       Symbol                                                        
2017-01-01 BTC     16050414526   998.33        1.607734e+07  1.642702e+10
           ETH       715049311     8.17        8.749380e+07  7.331980e+08
           XRP       231408729     0.01        3.633730e+10  3.633730e+08
           LTC       221718486     4.51        4.914415e+07  2.285203e+08
           XMR       190983552    13.97        1.366825e+07  2.193754e+08
           ETC       122202804     1.40        8.744412e+07  1.259195e+08
           DASH       78524020    11.23        6.992839e+06  8.258543e+07
           REP        43994860     4.00        1.100000e+07  4.609000e+07
           MAID       43862003     0.10        4.525524e+08  4.072972e+07
           STEEM      36999610     0.16        2.295821e+08  3.443731e+07
2017-01-02 BTC     16429072864  1021.75        1.607930e+07  1.678422e+10
           ETH       733331862     8.38        8.752531e+07  8.516212e+08
           XRP       229312859     0.01        3.633730e+10  3.633730e+08
           LTC       228536428     4.65        4.915883e+07  2.276054e+08
           XMR       219509938    16.05        1.367528e+07  2.200353e+08
           ETC       125743676     1.44        8.747679e+07  1.303404e+08
           DASH       82595831    11.81        6.994957e+06  8.939555e+07
           REP        46101566     4.19        1.100000e+07  4.697000e+07
           MAID       42320210     0.09        4.525524e+08  4.525524e+07
           STEEM      35374447     0.15        2.296454e+08  3.674327e+07
2017-01-03 BTC     16786354619  1043.84        1.608136e+07           NaN
           ETH       851511659     9.73        8.755683e+07           NaN
           XRP       232046528     0.01        3.633730e+10           NaN
           LTC       227483720     4.63        4.917295e+07           NaN
           XMR       220176407    16.09        1.368161e+07           NaN
           ETC       130608332     1.49        8.750880e+07           NaN
           DASH       89434687    12.78        6.997071e+06           NaN
           REP        46955890     4.27        1.100000e+07           NaN
           MAID       44863660     0.10        4.525524e+08           NaN
           STEEM      36308540     0.16        2.297532e+08           NaN
```

EDIT:

Get first 10 values per first day of months, reshape by `unstack` and set index to month period:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df.index.to_period('m'))
         .head(10)
         .set_index('Symbol', append=True)['Circulating.Supply']
         .unstack())
df1.index = df1.index.to_period('m').rename('month')
#print (df1)
```

Reshape similar and create MultiIndex with month period:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Symbol', append=True)['Price'].unstack()
df2.index = [df2.index, df2.index.to_period('m').rename('month')]
#print (df2)
```

Divide by months periods, remove helper level, reshape back and last add new column:

```
s = df2.div(df1, level=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).stack().rename('new')

df = df.join(s, on=['Date','Symbol'])
#print (df)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help. I was wondering, how can I shift values of the 'new' column so it starts with 2017-01-02 ? thanks

Comment: @rakamakafo - Yes, need `df.set_index(df.index - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))` for subtract one day to `df2`, check `print (df1)` and `print (df2)` for difference in `DatetimeIndex`

Comment: Your solution is working, but I am looking for the different output. Your solution multiplies the supply of the day by the price on the next day. I need to log the supply of the first 10 coins on the 1st day of each month and multiply it by the price on every other day of the month until the end of the month. And then repeat this operation for every month. So, for example 'New' on '2017-01-03' should be supply of BTC on the 1st day of the month times the price on the '2017-01-03' which is 1.607734e+07  * 1043.84

Comment: @rakamakafo - One question - Do you need extract top10 for each day and then apply solution in comment above? Or get top10 only for first day in month and then apply solution?

Comment: @rakamakafo - Added solution for divide by first 10rows per months.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and your genius solution. I just had to change change div to mul and I got the desired output. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into datetime indexes, this will work for the data you have presented. Note that if there is more than one month, you might need to use DateTimeIndex (perhaps using `.astype('datetime64[M]')`) to compare with the first for each month:

```
s = pd.Series(
         pd.concat([df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')]['Circulating.Supply'] * 
          df.loc[date]['Price'] 
      for date in df.index.get_level_values('Date').unique()])
                    .dropna())
df['New.Cap'] = s.values
```

Comment: Thank you for you solutiion, but I get a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.